# ListView keeps data even if you exit the page

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-provider, statefulwidget

Good morning/evening. Hope you are well.

I have a problem with my ListView.

I receive an Article object in the constructor of my EditArticlePage(StatefulWidget) and one of the properties of my Article is a List of links that I transmit in the constructor of my provider EditArticlePageProvider, then I retrieve these images which I display in a ListView.

When I delete an image from my ListView, it is deleted, so far, no problem ( 2 images - 1 image = 1 image).

But when I leave the EditArticlePage(press back button or back button on appbar), and come back to it, my ListView is kept with the modifications I made before, instead of the initial data of the Article.

P.S: all other data is reset except the ListView containing the images.

Here is my code:

My EditArticlePage class

```
class EditArticlePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Article article;

  EditArticlePage(this.article, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditArticlePageState createState() => _EditArticlePageState();
}

class _EditArticlePageState extends State<EditArticlePage> {

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ChangeNotifierProvider<EditArticlePageProvider>(
    create: (_) =>
        EditArticlePageProvider(originalImages: widget.article.imagesLinks),
    child: Consumer<EditArticlePageProvider>(
      builder: (context, editProvider, __) {
        final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            return Future<bool>.value(true);
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            body: ListView(
              children: [
                buildArticleImages(screenWidth, screenHeight, editProvider),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
}
```

buildArticleImages methodes

```
Widget buildArticleImages(double screenWidth, double screenHeight,
          EditArticlePageProvider editProvider) =>
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight * 0.15,
        child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            final imageLink = editProvider.originalImages[index];
            return Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeight * 0.15,
                  width: screenWidth * 0.35,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(9.0),
                      ),
                      child: Image.network(
                        imageLink,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: DeleteButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      editProvider.addToDeleteList(imageLink, index);
                      
                    },
                  ),
                  right: 3.0,
                  top: 3.0,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (_, index) => SizedBox(width: 5.0),
          itemCount: editProvider.originalImages.length,
        ),
      );
```

My provider

```
class EditArticlePageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List originalImages;

  EditArticlePageProvider({@required this.originalImages});
  

  List<String> imagesToDelete = [];
      
List<String> get imagesToDelete => _imagesToDelete;



void addToDeleteList(String imageLink, int index) {
    if (imageLink != null) {
      imagesToDelete.add(imageLink);
      originalImages.removeAt(index);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

}

May you guy help me please ? And tell me if i'm doing wrong  something THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `originalImages` and the `widget.article.imagesLinks` are actually references to the same list object, when `originalImages.removeAt(index);` in `addToDeleteList` method, it will remove the image at the index of this list object and the two references are affected.

Then, if you want to keep the images in `widget.article.imagesLinks`, you can copy the list in `EditArticlePageProvider`:

```
EditArticlePageProvider({@required List originalImages}) : this.originalImages = List.of(originalImages);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @zhpoo, I noticed my mistake, soon I will try not to reproduce it anymore.

Comment: Do you have a link to a page or anything else to explain me how to copy an `Object` without the old reference ? Thanks again